# Changing default output style in BlueSky Statistics

Tags: default

I read that BlueSky Statistics will write all its output into publication-ready form (APA style) but my output always looks like Excel tables. Can it really do that, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can change that default setting by choosing Configuration Settings from the Options menu. Then choose the "Others" tab, and you'll see the option you need toward the bottom of that window. It's labeled, "Show output tables in APA (American Psychological Association) Style." Finally, click "Save" to keep the settings for the future.

You'll have to re-run your analyses before you see the changes. Older output will retain its original look.

The APA style tables will retain their interactivity, so you can still sort on any column.

Note that this feature was added in version 5.35, so if you don't see it, you probably need to download the latest version.